# how to create hostname, password & JID in xmpp jabbed server for iOS app

Tags: ios, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am stuck with creating JID, hostname and password for my xmpp server.

I installed ejabberd server in my Mac but I don't know how to create hostname, password and JID!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first days using a new software can be confusing, as everything is new (how to configure, how to administer, how to use, how to restart it): be patient and learn slowly, later things will be a lot easier :)

There are several methods to register an account:

A) You (as administrator) can register a XMPP account in the ejabberd server using the `ejabberdctl` command line tool, for example:

```
ejabberdctl register hari localhost mypassword
User hari@localhost successfully registered
```

See https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/installation/#administration-account

B) If `mod_register` is enabled in the ejabberd configuration file, and it allows account registration, then you (as a normal user) can use a Jabber/XMPP client that supports In-Band Registration to register the account.

See https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-register

C) If ejabberd has `mod_register_web` enabled, then you (as a normal user) can access the registration page to register an account.

See https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-register-web

Comment: I'm really grateful; it worked. To be quite honest, I don't know anything about the mod register, albeit I should. I appreciate you offering the documents.

Comment: Were you able to solve the question? Did this answer help? Then mark this answer as useful, so the question can be closed.